# how to check if a specific file extension exists in a folder using powershell?

Tags: file, powershell, directory, exists

I have a root directory that consists of many folders and sub folders. I need to check whether a particular file like *.sln or *.designer.vb exists in the folders or subfolders and output the result in a text file.

For Eg:

```
$root = "C:\Root\"
$FileType = ".sln",".designer.vb"
```

the text file will have result somewhat like below:

```
.sln ---> 2 files
.sln files path ----> 
c:\Root\Application1\subfolder1\Test.sln
c:\Root\Application2\subfolder1\Test2.sln
```

Any help will be highly appreciated!

Regards,
Ashish

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

```
function Get-ExtensionCount {
    param(
        $Root = "C:\Root\",
        $FileType = @(".sln", ".designer.vb"),
        $Outfile = "C:\Root\rootext.txt"
    )

    $output = @()

    Foreach ($type in $FileType) {
        $files = Get-ChildItem $Root -Filter *$type -Recurse | ? { !$_.PSIsContainer }
        $output += "$type ---> $($files.Count) files"
        foreach ($file in $files) {
            $output += $file.FullName
        }
    }

    $output | Set-Content $Outfile
}
```

I turned it into a function with your values as default parameter-values. Call it by using

```
Get-ExtensionCount    #for default values
```

Or

```
Get-ExtensionCount -Root "d:\test" -FileType ".txt", ".bmp" -Outfile "D:\output.txt"
```

Output saved to the file ex:

```
.txt ---> 3 files
D:\Test\as.txt
D:\Test\ddddd.txt
D:\Test\sss.txt
.bmp ---> 2 files
D:\Test\dsadsa.bmp
D:\Test\New Bitmap Image.bmp
```

To get the all the filecounts at the start, try:

```
function Get-ExtensionCount {
    param(
        $Root = "C:\Root\",
        $FileType = @(".sln", ".designer.vb"),
        $Outfile = "C:\Root\rootext.txt"
    )
    #Filecount per type
    $header = @()
    #All the filepaths    
    $filelist = @()

    Foreach ($type in $FileType) {
        $files = Get-ChildItem $Root -Filter *$type -Recurse | ? { !$_.PSIsContainer }
        $header += "$type ---> $($files.Count) files"
        foreach ($file in $files) {
            $filelist += $file.FullName
        }
    }
    #Collect to single output
    $output = @($header, $filelist)    
    $output | Set-Content $Outfile
}
```

Comment: Hi Graimer, Thanks for your response. After I call this function through the command prompt I get: cmdlet set-content at command pipeline pos 1. supply values for the parameters.. and the parameters are endless :(

Comment: This happends when you call exactly `Get-ExtensionCount` ? Did you copy the function 100%? Especially the last line. `$output | Set-Content $Outfile`. I think you forgot to include `$Outfile` at the end. Script works on PS2.0 and PS3.0. You could also try to switch the line with `$output | Set-Content -Path $Outfile` but it shouldn't matter.

Comment: Yes.. I had missed that :-) But in the output I get .sln--->44 files , .suo --->  files.. but none show the files and file paths.

Comment: oh, sorry. forgot about one PS3.0 feature. see updated answer

Comment: is there a way I can print the output in the manner where all the types of files and their counts come in first and all the file paths come in the last.. .sln--->34 files .suo--->120 files then comes the filepaths

Comment: Updated answer. See the last codesample (untested, don't have PS here). :-)

Answer (score 5):

Here's a one-liner to determine if at least one file with extension .txt or .ps1 exists in the directory $OutputPath:

```
(Get-ChildItem -Path $OutputPath -force | Where-Object Extension -in ('.txt','.ps1') | Measure-Object).Count
```

**Explanation**: the command tells you the number of files in the specified directory matching any of the listed extensions. You can append `-ne 0` to the end, which returns true or false to be used in an **if** block.

Comment: Best answer for me on here +1. In case anyone may want the regex version, here's that. `(Get-ChildItem -Path $OutputPath -force | Where-Object Extension -match ('\.jpe?g') | Measure-Object).Count` Which will match either jpeg or jpg.

Answer (score 0):

This will search the directory `$root` and its subdirectories for files of type `$FileType`, including hidden files and excluding directories:

```
$root = "C:\Root\";
$FileType = "*.sln", "*.designer.vb";
$results = Get-ChildItem -Path $root -Force -Recurse `
    | Where-Object {
        if ($_ -isnot [System.IO.DirectoryInfo])
        {
            foreach ($pattern in $FileType)
            {
                if ($_.Name -like $pattern)
                {
                    return $true;
                }
            }
        }

        return $false;
    }
```

Note that I've modified the strings in `$FileType` to be formatted as a wildcard pattern.  Then group the files by extension:

```
$resultGroups = $results | Group-Object -Property 'Extension';
```

Then loop through each group and print the file count and paths:

```
foreach ($group in $resultGroups)
{
    # $group.Count: The number of files with that extension
    # $group.Group: A collection of FileInfo objects
    #  $group.Name: The file extension with leading period
    Write-Host "$($group.Name) ---> $($group.Count) files";
    Write-Host "$($group.Name) files path ---->";

    foreach ($file in $group.Group)
    {
        Write-Host $file.FullName;
    }
}
```

To write the results to a file instead of the console, use the [`Out-File` cmdlet](http://technet.microsoft.com/library/hh849882.aspx) instead of the [`Write-Host` cmdlet](http://technet.microsoft.com/library/hh849877.aspx).

Comment: Filter doesn't support array input(multiple fileext.)

Comment: Yes, just realizing that now.

Comment: You could however modify it to use `if ($FileType -contains $group.Name) { ...` in you foreach loop instead of the Filter

Comment: That would work, but then `Group-Object` would end up processing files and creating groups that might ultimately end up being ignored.  Instead, I changed the call to `Get-ChildItem` to retrieve all files and the filtering is now performed inside of `Where-Object`.  I made a slight change to the format of `$FileType` to facilitate this.